# Spring Boot custom login page causing circular view path exception

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a secured Spring Boot application with the following configuration classes.  When I browse to my app, I get redirected to `/login`, but the server throws a servlet exception with the message `Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again.`  My application is an AngularJS app, so there's no server side view rendering.  I have a login.html page located in /src/main/resources/static.  I've tried creating an `@Configuration` class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in order to add a view controller for `/login`, but that didn't seem to solve it.  That class was in the same package as my `Application` class.

**Application**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({CommonsJpaConfig.class})
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private PersonRepository personRepository;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        }

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return (email) -> personRepository.findByEmail(email)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find the user with email '" + email + "'."));
        }
    }
}
```

**Minimal login.html for testing**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried setting a target url after login to see whether it will actually redirect to ti?

Comment: Not sure what that will do since I can't even see the login page itself.

Comment: Ahh so you can't actually see the login page, understand now, thanks for clarification. Are you able to show us the login.html page code please, at least the login form part of it.

Comment: Sure, but right now it's a very minimal page without even a form.  I'm just trying to get it to appear before I create the form.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem seems to be solved when I rename `login.html` to something other, like `loginpage.html`. Apparently the route to the view is confused with the url of the static page.